# Missing lxss folder in Windows, can't access Ubuntu's files

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I installed a Linux Ubuntu subsystem onto my Windows 10. 
Ubuntu itself works fine and I can access all the Windows files without a problem.

But somehow I can't access the files the other way around, meaning I can't find the lxss folder where all the files from Ubuntu are stored.

I already made all folders visible, even the system ones. There just isn't a lxss folder.

In fact, there is not a single lxss folder on the whole drive.

Ubuntu must save the files somewhere, I just don't know where...

Comment: If you installed the new way from the Windows Store, as opposed to the legacy beta installation, then the root filesystem is in "%LocalAppData%\Packages\<Package Name>\LocalState\rootfs", where the package name is like "CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_*".

Comment: Note that these files are not supposed to be accessed from Windows applications. File metadata could be lost.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, can you tell me if windows access rights could interfere with the ubuntu system then?

Comment: The root filesystem is on NTFS, so ultimately the file security (owner, DACL, integrity level) filters the available access in WSL. But there's no reason to modify it. The WSL user has full control of these files.